# Regular expression to match whole string containing a subset

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a good handle of regex but here is one thing I am having trouble with.

I have this string:

```
foo xxx bar   z
```

I want to match the WHOLE string ONLY if foo AND bar are on it regardless of order.

I have this so far, but I need to capture the whole string:

```
(?=foo|bar)[^\s]+
```

Comment: Would this solve your problem? `~.*(foo|bar).*(foo|bar).*~ims`

Comment: It has to have at least one `foo` and at least one `bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(.*)$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdpdBS/2/)**

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?=.*\bfoo\b)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current line contains the word `foo` surrounded by word-boundaries.
- `(?=.*\bbar\b)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current line contains the word `bar` surrounded by word-boundaries.
- `(.*)` - matches and captures 0+ occurrences of any character but a newline character.
- `$` - asserts the end of the line.

Comment: This one takes the cake. No repeating of flipped order.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is something like this:

```
(.*foo.+bar.*)|(.*bar.+foo.*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3SQhg2/1

---

Edit: I missed the point that the `foo` and `bar` must occur as a whole word. Here is the fix:

For the order foo -> bar

```
^.*\bfoo\b.*bar\b.*$
```

For the order bar -> foo (by simply swapping `foo` and `bar` in the previous one)

```
^.*\bbar\b.*foo\b.*$
```

Both combined:

```
^.*\bfoo\b.*bar\b.*$|^.*\bbar\b.*foo\b.*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3SQhg2/4

Comment: I think OP doesn't want this to match `aa foobb bar`

Comment: @choz You are right. Thank you for pointing out! I improved my answer.

Comment: We thought the same thing. But I accepted Potato's answer because it's shorter and doesn't have the mirrored/repeated regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I wanted to delete this, but maybe someone else will have this question too so I'll just post my answer here as well.

```
^
(                    # let's start capturing
 .*                  # if there's something before the two words
 (?:
  (?=\bfoo\b)\w+     # match the first word
  .*                 # if there's something in the middle of the two words
  (?=\bbar\b)\w+     # match the second word
  |                  # OR let's do everything above but in reverse this time
  (?=\bbar\b)\w+
  .*
  (?=\bfoo\b)\w+
 )
 .*                  # if there's something after the two words
)
$
```

Which matches+captures:

```
foo xxx bar   z
```

and

```
yy bar z foo xxx
```

but not

```
aa foobb bar
```

and

```
xx bar xfoo
```

https://regex101.com/r/3wzFh3/2

Comment: adding to much `positive lookahead` may cause overhead. 

You might want to compare the results here: https://regex101.com/r/3wzFh3/3
and here https://regex101.com/r/3wzFh3/4

(See the results section at the top right in the green area.)